# Passing value from function to woocommerce hook

Tags: php, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, cart, price

In Woocommerce I'm trying to pass some value from a custom  simple function to a hooked function in **"woocommerce_before_calculate_totals"** action hook. But I get always an empty value.

I tried to dump the `$new_price` in `add_custom_item_price(`) function and its still **`int(0)`**. 
I also tried to dump `$_POST['fabric_length']` in `add_custom_item_price()` function and its **`NULL`**.

This is my code:

```
function calculate_new_price() {
    global $post;

    $category = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat');
    $meter_price = get_field('meter_price');
    $price_per_centimeter = $meter_price / 100;
    $total_height_price = $_POST['fabric_length'] * $price_per_centimeter;

    return $total_height_price;
}

$new_price = calculate_new_price();

add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_item_price', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_item_price( $cart_object ) {
    global $new_price; <------ returns int(0) when var_dump in this function

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    foreach (  $cart_object->get_cart() as $item_values ) {
        $item_values['data']->set_price(ceil($new_price));
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your post is null and you multiply Null * something you'll get 0. You must investigate why your post is not being sent correctly.

Comment: $category is an unused variable btw.

Comment: @Hooli yes it is, forgot to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update…

Here is a complete code (verifiable), with frontend and backend custom fields that will show you the correct way to make it work on advanced customizations without the need of using Advanced custom fields:

```
// Frontend: The product custom field [FOR TESTING]
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'fabric_length_product_field' );
function fabric_length_product_field() {
    global $product;
    // The fake calculated price
    ?>
        <div>
            <label class="product-custom-text-label" for="servicetime"><?php _e( 'Fabric lenght:', 'woocommerce'); ?><br>
                <input type="text" id="fabric_length" name="fabric_length" value="">
            </label>
        </div><br>
    <?php
}

// Backend: Add a custom field to product in backend [FOR TESTING]
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'add_field_product_options_pricing' );
function add_field_product_options_pricing() {
    global $post;

    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_meter_price',
        'label'         => __('Metter price', 'woocommerce') . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
        'placeholder'   => __('Set the Metter price…', 'woocommerce'),
        'description'   => __('Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce'),
        'desc_tip'      => 'true',
    ));

    echo '</div>';
}

// Save product custom field to database when submitted in Backend [FOR TESTING]
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_product_options_custom_fields', 30, 1 );
function save_product_options_custom_fields( $post_id ){
    // Saving custom field value
    if( isset( $_POST['_meter_price'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_meter_price', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_meter_price'] ) );
    }
}

// Add custom calculated price conditionally as custom data to cart items
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_price_to_cart_item_data', 20, 2 );
function add_custom_price_to_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
    if( ! isset($_POST['fabric_length']) )
        return $cart_item_data;

    // Get your data
    $meter_price = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_meter_price', true );
    if( empty($meter_price) || $meter_price == 0 )
        return $cart_item_data;

    $fabric_length = (float) sanitize_text_field( $_POST['fabric_length'] );
    if( empty($fabric_length) || $fabric_length == 0 )
        return $cart_item_data;

    // Price Calculations and saving
    $cart_item_data['custom_price'] = ceil( $fabric_length * $meter_price / 100 );
    $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() ); // Make each item unique

    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Set conditionally a custom item price
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_cutom_cart_item_price', 20, 1);
function set_cutom_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach (  $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( isset( $cart_item['custom_price'] ) )
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['custom_price'] );
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: Thank you, @LoicTheAztec but $cart_item['custom_price'] is still null

Comment: @Webbie You should add in your question all the related code (meaning the custom field in single product pages) and the settings of your advanced custom field in admin edit product pages with screenshots… Without that I can't reproduce the problem. My code works … I have test it. Now you should avoid using advanced custom fields for this kind of customization… **Coding product custom fields in backend and front end is easy and maid for advanced customizations like in here.**